# Observing anko database changes in activities

Tags: android, kotlin, observer-pattern, android-livedata, anko

I'm currently building an app from the ground up and can't figure out how to get my views to automatically update when my database is updated. The DB is implemented using anko's sqlite. I've left a lot out for the sake of brevity, but the repository includes more management methods like insertion and deletion which are working.

I'm instantiating arrayAdapters in my activities based on the list returned by this repository, but currently only in the `onCreate()` method.

`filesystemList = FilesystemRepository(this).getAllFilesystems()`

Rather than attempt to manually manage lifecycle awareness, I'd love to use something like `LiveData` to make my life easier.

Could anyone explain to me how to properly do this, or point me to an example?

Here is an example model:

```
data class Filesystem(val name: String,
                      val realRoot: Boolean,
                      val location: String,
                      val type: String,
                      val dateCreated: String) {
    companion object {
        val TABLE_NAME = "Filesystem"
        val COLUMN_FILESYSTEM_ID = "filesystemId"
        val COLUMN_NAME = "name"
        val COLUMN_REAL_ROOT  = "realRoot"
        val COLUMN_LOCATION = "location"
        val COLUMN_TYPE = "type"
        val COLUMN_DATE_CREATED = "dateCreated"
    }
}
```

The repository I've wrapped it in:

```
class FilesystemRepository(val context: Context) {
    fun getAllFilesystems(): ArrayList<Filesystem> {
        return ArrayList(context.database.use {
            select(Filesystem.TABLE_NAME).exec {
                parseList(parser)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And the database itself:

```
    class DatabaseOpenHelper(context: Context): ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper(context, "AppDatabase") {
    companion object {
        private var instance: DatabaseOpenHelper? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context): DatabaseOpenHelper {
            if(instance == null) {
                instance = DatabaseOpenHelper(context.applicationContext)
            }
            return instance!!
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(database: SQLiteDatabase) {
        database.createTable(Filesystem.TABLE_NAME, true,
                Filesystem.COLUMN_FILESYSTEM_ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY + AUTOINCREMENT,
                Filesystem.COLUMN_NAME to TEXT + UNIQUE(ConflictClause.FAIL),
                Filesystem.COLUMN_REAL_ROOT to INTEGER,
                Filesystem.COLUMN_LOCATION to TEXT,
                Filesystem.COLUMN_TYPE to TEXT,
                Filesystem.COLUMN_DATE_CREATED to TEXT
        )
}


val Context.database: DatabaseOpenHelper
    get() = DatabaseOpenHelper.getInstance(applicationContext)
```

Comment: Create a function where you will check is your list with data first `null` and than `empty` if both are negative `clear` the list. Than populate the list again with data from `database` and notify the `adapter` that data is changed. You can call this function after data is updated successfully.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid implementing life cycle awareness manually for each model for each activity. It seems error prone and I'd like to learn techniques for implementing best practices.

Comment: Than use `static` variables and save values in them they can be accessible in all parts of your app and they will keep values as long as app is not destroyed.

Comment: There isn't even a static keyword in Kotlin.